# How is import assets from './assets' resolved in React Starter Kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-starter-kit

In the `server.js` the assets [are imported](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/e61838ad6ce7b57773623a42494470fd8b2c73c7/src/server.js#L30) like this

```
import assets from './assets';
```

If I understood it correctly this path maps to `build/public/assets` which is generated through the webpack configuration here:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/public/assets'),
  publicPath: '/assets/',
  sourcePrefix: '  ',
  pathinfo: isVerbose,
},
```

Or am I mistaken on that? When I run `webpack` I still run into:

```
ERROR in ./src/server.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./assets
```

Basically the question here is not how to get it run, but why can the line `import assets from './assets';` in the React Starter Kit be resolved even though there is no `assets.js` inside `src`.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn No, check out the link in the top, that' show they have written it, I didn't come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build the project first:

```
npm run build
```

this creates the build folder with the assets.js file in it.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I know how to check out the project and run the commands, I am trying to understand how the line `import assets form './assets` works even though there is no `assets.js` in the `src` folder

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/e61838ad6ce7b57773623a42494470fd8b2c73c7/tools/webpack.config.js) file in the `/tools` folder.

It's using [`assets-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/assets-webpack-plugin) to bundle assets into namespaced `client` and `vender` modules.

After running `npm run build`, webpack outputs the resulting builds to the `build/public/assets` folder. Since the `src/server.js` is referencing `./assets` as a relative, not fixed path, it will work once it's bundled and you run `server.js` from the `build/public` dir.

This ReadMe is also helpful: [Build Automation Tools](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/e61838ad6ce7b57773623a42494470fd8b2c73c7/tools#build-automation-tools).